# Ignore/Delete Repeat Symbols in a Frequency List in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I'm unsure how to get this function to only return the frequency of a symbol once if it appears more than 1 time in the list. At the moment `(freq-list '(This is a really really good test))` returns `((this . 1) (is . 1) (a . 1) (really . 2) (really . 1) (good . 1) (test . 1))` But I would like only the `(really . 2)` to appear and it to omit the `(really . 1)` Thanks in advance.

```
(define (num-occurs sym lst)
  (define (num-occurs-helper sym lst counter)
    (cond ((null? lst) counter)
          ((equal? sym (car lst))(num-occurs-helper sym (cdr lst) (+ counter 1)))
          (else (num-occurs-helper sym (cdr lst) counter))))
  (num-occurs-helper sym lst 0))

(define (freq-list lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        (else (cons
               (cons (car lst)
                     (num-occurs (car lst) lst))
               (freq-list (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: You should also post your `num-occurs` procedure.

Comment: Ah sorry about that. It's been added :)

Comment: Have you already learned about "named  let"?

Comment: It's a duplicate, and you'll have to do a bit more of work to correctly count the frequencies of each element. Better not to reinvent the wheel, take a look at the linked post, in particular scroll down to the part where `bagify` is defined.